# RuntimeWarning shows once and then disappears - how to make it persistent?

Tags: python, numpy, warnings

When running Python in interactive mode, `RuntimeWarning` is issued once and then disappears.

Here's an example session:

```py
>> import numpy as np
>> arr = np.array([np.inf])
>>
>> arr - arr #  <-- first time
>> <stdin>:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
array([nan])
>>
>> arr - arr #  <-- second time, no warning!
array([nan])
```

I'm experiencing this in Windows cmd (python 3.10) and also in Google Colab Jupyter notebook.

What's the reason, and how can I make the warning appear every time?

Answer (score 0):

Python warnings only triggered once by default. You can change that globally by

`import warnings; warnings.simplefilter("always")`

or locally within a `warnings.catch_warnings()`  context manager. See the official python docs about the warnings module for more info

Comment: I see. So if we see warnings issued each time, [as here for example](https://www.online-python.com/aYIzDpWqv7), it just means the default behavior was changed in that environment?

Comment: Quite likely, yes. No idea about that specific interpreter though